# Character encoding when reading a csv file

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am reading a list of urls from a csv file and am getting these 'AC0' etc. for where there are hyphens in the url. I have tried using .encode('utf-8') etc but not had any success so far.

```
with open('supermarkets/sains_urls.csv') as f: 
content1=f.readlines()
content1 = [x.strip() for x in content1]
```

'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/potatoes/sainsburys+AC0-baking+AC0-potatoes+AC0-25kg+AC0-6001324+AC0-p+AC0-44',

What do I need to do so that the urls are read/display normally?

Comment: You have encoded URLs, those are not a character encoding but a domain-specific way to encode data in URLs.

Comment: However, each of those `+AC0` entries looks like noise; if your input file has those then something that *wrote the file* caused those to be added. How did the CSV file get generated? Any chance you can give us a hexdump of the file contents (just the first lines would do)?